# How to call a method at exactly the same interval of time in a loop?

Tags: java, time, fixed

In Java, I have a loop which calls a method, and then that method has a sin which takes as parameter the time since the execution of the program. This loop runs at constant 60 updates per second (with the expected variations of +-1 or 2 ups). What I want to do is call a method within that loop, but that method must be called every 0.2, 0.4... seconds (fixed interval) , so what I did was:
    `if(executionTime % 200 == 0)`
But that wasn't enough because it isn't always exact so it skipped a lot of times. For that matter I tried `if(executionTime % 200 <= 50)` to try and limit it, but it still skipped a few times, but less than before. So my question is if there is any way to have it run exactly at 0.2 seconds, with the following details:

- If the loop takes more than 0.2 seconds for one iteration, then call the method.
- If it takes less than 0.2 seconds, I'm not sure because if it is 30 ms, then obviously not, but if it is 198 ms then yes, within a small margin.

What I'm using this is to call sin with a variable that is incremented by some number every time the method is called (this is where the method must be called every 200 ms). Essentialy I want to do something similar to graphing a function that depends on time(X), where X is incremented by the same number every 200 ms of loop iteration. So, each loop iteration, a new point of the graph is calculated every 200 ms. What I could do is check before each call to other methods within the loop if it is time to call this method, but that ruins the order of the loop. I've searched around, but I can only find scheduling, which I believe doesn't do it.

EDIT: Pseudocode:

```
int increment;

while(running){
    first();
    second();

    if(condition)
        doSomething();
    if(timeCheck) // time check every 200ms; this is what I don't know how to do
        graphfunction(increment);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Thread? paste your code at here..

Comment: I have not tried Thread because I'm not yet familiar with it threads, but wouldn't that make it unpredictable since threads may not be running in parallel?

Comment: Delete 50% of your text and replace it with actual code of your loop.

Comment: Why not just `if (200 - exceutionTime > 0) { Thread.sleep(200 - exceutionTime) }` ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've been switching from C++ to Java and don't really have a code yet, but I will write up a pseudocode.

Comment: Your pseudocode implies that you want your loop running as fast as possible, but calling `graphFunction` only whenever 200 ms have passed since the last time it was called. Is that correct? If, on the other hand, you want one iteration each 200 ms, that's a completely different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `java.util.concurrent`'s `ExecutorService`. Take a look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Use the following method on that object

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

Javadoc:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
>   that is executions will commence after initialDelay then
>   initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but is there any way to have more control over this, because it runs automatically. For example, start it, stop it, add parameters to the Runnable command, because it isn't very flexible.

Comment: Actually, I made a new class that implements Runnable and got it to accept parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.sleep()

```
    long time1 ,time2;
    while (true) {
        time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        yourMethod();
        time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if((time2-time1) <200)
        Thread.sleep(200-(time2-time1)); 

    }
```

Comment: This will then take more than 200ms for one loop, because `yourMethod()` is not returning instantly (is it?), so `Thread.sleep(200)` will only be called when `yourMethod()` has finished execution.

Comment: This works, thank you. However it doesn't take into account the rest of the loop and sleeps only the time required for the method, and the rest of the loop is more important than this. Also, shouldn't it be `Thread.sleep(200-(time2-time1));`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something graphical, probably for the Swing GUI. Use a [swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), instead of looping. This is optimal. If the calculation takes too long, drop a frame: check on a timer callback doing the calculation, whether no prior calculation is still being done.

In fact, if you on the timer callback display the calculated result of the prior calculation, `repaint` / `repaintImmediately`, and then start the next calculation, the frame rate is held as exact as possible.

Maybe using double buffering:

```
BufferedImage actualShown = new BufferedImage(...);

// Could be local to graphfunction:
BufferedImage beingCalculated = new BufferedImage(...);

@Override
public void repaintComponent(Graphics g) { // Called via repaint
    g.drawImage(actualShown, 0, 0);
}

void graphfunction(int increment) {
    // First draw old frame:
    repaint();

    // Calculations:
    ... beingCalculation.setRGB(x, y, Color.BLACK);

    // Double buffering:
    BufferedImage next = actualShown;
    actualShown = beingCalculated;
    beingCalculated = next;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good option, I will try to implement it, thank you.